# Ubuntu setup crashing live USB

Tags: live-usb, crash

I am trying to install Ubuntu 15.10 on my PC. When I choose "Install Ubuntu", I get the first step of installation without the text and then the setup crashes with a message saying, "Ubuntu has encountered an internal error."

Answer (score 0):

Test your USB in other system also. Also check whether the .iso you have put on the bootable USB is not corrupt. I had experienced this problem in these two scenario only.

In general I always use [this program](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) for creating bootable USB